# DependencyProperty Inheritance of Language property for ChildWindow / ToolTip

Tags: silverlight

in my Application_Startup I have the following code at the end:

```
(this.RootVisual as FrameworkElement).Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
```

The language property is automatically inherited by all controls as expected, except ToolTips and ChildWindows (which are shown by "TooltipService / ChildWindow.Show() method).

Is this because they are not part of the visual-tree?

How to easily propagate the language to those controls as well?
(I don't want to put the above code in each and every control, which might be in a tooltip/childwindow...)

Any ideas?

Regards

Johannes Colmsee